# how do i change the elemends on the first and the last column

Tags: c

I would like to change the numbers on the first and the last column and i can't do it. I also want to change the numabers at the corners of the table to the half -sum of the elemends above and below them.

Please be nice it's my second time writing code .

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
#define M 20

int load(double x[N][M]);
int print(double x[N][M]);
void printthearray(double x[N][M]);
int calculatetemperature(void);

int main(void) {
  double data[N][M];
  print((double(*)[M])data);

  return 0;
}
int print(double x[N][M]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < M - 1; i++) {
    printf("2.00  ", x[i][0]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
      printf("1.00  ", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    printf("3.00  ", x[i][9]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `printf`s are obviously wrong. Compare what _you_ did with what was told you in your learning material. Also compile with `-Wall` (warnings enabled).

Comment: Start with `printf`, which is ill formed, if you pass a parameter of type double to it you'll need a specifier to actually print the value, *i.e.* `printf("%lf", x[i][0])`, you then need to initialize the actual elements of the array.

Comment: @anastaciu: the correct conversion for `double` is `%f`. The `l` modifier "has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier" (C standard 7.21.6.1 paragraph 7) and is usually discouraged because of the possible confusion with `Lf` (for `long double`)

Comment: It's not actually all that clear what you are trying to do here. Ignoring the failure to initialize `data`: You say you want to *"change"* certain elements of your array, but you are only attempting to print them. Are you under the assumption that a statement like `printf("1.00  ", x[i][j]);` places the floating point value `1.00` in `x[i][j]`? If not, since the newlines would seem to indicate you are meaning to print, what is the significance of `2.00` in the first column and `3.00` in the last? If you are trying to print...

Comment: ...then note that the indicies in `x[i][9]` are flipped, and the nested loops should probably start from `1` (with the outer being `i < 9`, although again, it's unclear what the intent is). Be careful not to confuse yourself with the output you produce; currently the first column will be printed as a line (visually a row) of output. Additionally, it would be better to consistently use `N` and `M` throughout, to clean up some magic numbers. What are `load`, `printthearray`, and `calculatetemperature`?

Comment: @rici I wasn't aware thanks for the info. I've noticed that there is no problem, but thought that it was the canonical way of doing it.

Comment: It's needed in `scanf` though, maybe the source of my confusion.

Comment: thank you everyone so much , i solved in a different way,that was just stupid